# Get Completed Documents without attachments

Tags: pdf-generation, docusignapi

I am using REST API's **Get Envelope Documents and Certificate** call to retrieve completed documents. It retrieves all pdf documents with attachments as a byte stream. From which I can't separate pdf documents from attachments. How can I separate pdf documents from attachments or Can I get pdf documents and attachments separately from two calls using REST API. I don't want both documents and attachments as one byte stream.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can separate them, there is actually an account setting that controls whether or not signer attachments are concatenated to the PDF docs.  To modify this account setting:

1. Login to the Console (demo.docusign.net for demo, www.docusign.net for production)
2. Select profile icon in the top right of the screen.
3. Select **Preferences** and on the following screen scroll down and select **Features**.
4. Find the option labeled "Concatenate Signer Attachment Documents to the Parent Document" and un-check if you do *not* want them concatenated.

[image]

Comment: This option was already unselected, but still I am getting pdf documents with attachments. Is there something else that I am not doing?

Comment: It's possible there's a bug with the api here.  What happens when you download completed documents through the Console, does the option seem to affect those at?

Comment: No the option does not has any affect when envelope downloaded through console either.